# PHP Static Method Using Private Class Functions/Variables

Tags: php, static, methods

If I write a public static method in a class ie...

```
public static function get_info($type){
        switch($type){
            case'title':
                self::get_title(); 
                break;
        }
    }
```

I have to write my get_title() function as public...

```
public static function get_title(){
        return 'Title';
    }
```

Otherwise I get the error:

```
Call to private method Page::get_title()
```

Which makes me feel as though the function `get_info()` is essentially redundant.  I'd like to be able to make a call from a static method to a private method inside my class for validation purposes.  Is this impossible?

PHP > 5.0 btw.

!####### EDIT SOLUTION (BUT NOT ANSWER TO QUESTION) #########!

In case you are curious, my workaround was to instantiate my static function's class inside the static function.

So, the class name was Page I would do this...

```
public static function get_info($type){
            $page = new Page();
            switch($type){
                case'title':
                    $page->get_title(); 
                    break;
            }
        }
  public function get_title(){
            return 'Title';
        }
```

Comment: I was under the impression that this was possible and indeed I can (after some checking) confirm to have done this on several occasions. Are you sure `get_info()` and `get_title()` are in the same class? It won’t work if `get_title()` resides in a superclass…

Comment: what happens then, when you refer to $this in the called non-static function?

Comment: @raphael... I tried, man.  The error I got above was a result of calling the get_title() method "private".

Comment: @nicolas78 - True, you can't refer to `$this` as there is no object instance, and you can't use `$this` to call a static method anyway. But you can use `self::` to refer to the static class that the method is in, in order to call other methods (private, protected or public) in that static class.

Comment: @Jascha - I also tried your code (both methods in the same class) and it works OK `get_title()` with private access.

Comment: @w3d - no, not to call a static method. but you should be able to use it in the non-static one you're supposedly calling from the static one. which value should it ever have?

Comment: @nicolas78 The called method is `static` as well, just `private` and `static`.

Comment: @Raphael - I don't think so, from the wording of the post. But we can't know for sure because we don't see the offending code

Comment: @nicolas78 - Yes, to call a static method! I agree with @Raphael. @Jascha - You should not be instantiating the class inside the 'static' class just to get around a problem of 'access'! It would be interesting to see your working example that you say produces this error? See my **working** example below using just a static class and your static methods above.

Comment: @nicolas78 - Yep, we don't know for sure because the above code does not produce an error - so we don't know where exactly this error is coming from. However, both methods (posted above) are static and one calls the other, so I would assume we just wrap that in a class?

Comment: @w3d I thank you for your input on this.  I'm kinda digging on instantiating my class from inside the class as I can resort to all my calls via the static method (keeps my html clean).  I'm not sure why I was getting the error above, It must have been syntax... either way, thank you for your input.

Comment: What is Page , just a class in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, it's impossible - a non-static method needs an object to read data from, while the point of a static one is that it has no such object attached. you can think of each non-static method of being passed an implicit argument, the object. you simply don't have a value to pass this value on to the method if you're calling from a static function.

**update**
you can have private static function - I'm not sure if your question might involve a slight misunderstanding of private and static as mutually exclusive concepts

Comment: So static methods inside of a class or really just utility functions in a "name space" wrapper?

Comment: Basically, yes. They can also access static data (although this is another word for global variables, so the usual warnings apply).

Comment: What's _impossible_ here? I'm not sure that this is answering the question?

Comment: well if the question is 'is this impossible', 'yes it's impossible' sure seems like a valid answer at least syntactically :)

Comment: of course syntax isn't everything and so I was trying to argue that even if it should turn out possible syntactically for some odd reason, there is no semantics to what such a call could possibly mean

Answer (score 11):

This is actually OK, there is nothing *impossible* here as far as I can see. Your static `get_title()` method can be private - or have I missed something? If both your static methods, `get_info()` and `get_title()`, are **in the same class** (whether it's *static* or not) then your `get_title()` method can be private and your code still works without error. `get_info()` calls `get_title()` inside the class - statically. `get_title()` does not need to be public in your example, unless it needs to be accessible from outside that static class.

Access (public, protected and private) applies to static classes (where all methods are static) as well as class instances.

**EDIT:** You don't need to resort to instantiating the class in order to implement the private access...

```
// Enable full error reporting to make sure all is OK
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);

class MyStaticClass {

 public static function get_info($type){
  switch($type){
   case 'title':
    return self::get_title(); 
    break;
   }
 }


 private static function get_title() {
  return 'Title';
 }
}

// OK - get_info() calls the private method get_title() inside the static class
echo MyStaticClass::get_info('title');

// ERROR - get_title() is private so cannot be called from outside the class
echo MyStaticClass::get_title();
```